# PATH environment variable (

Tags: path

I have a question.
When I add to the **$PATH** variable a directory, dooes the system recognizes as commands only the executables inside that directory or does it also recognizes the executables in subdirectories of that directory and executables in subdirectories of the first subdirectory of the directory.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can test that yourself

```
$ mkdir play
$ cd play
$ echo 'echo "I am the outer script"' > outer_script
$ chmod +x outer_script

$ mkdir inner
$ echo 'echo "I am the inner script"' > inner/inner_script
$ chmod +x inner/inner_script

$ export PATH=$(pwd):$PATH
$ cd ~
```

To see what we did:

```
$ tree
.
├── inner
│   └── inner_script
└── outer_script
```

Try running both of them

```
$ outer_script
I am the outer script
$ inner_script
No such file or directory
```

So, the answer is no.

Comment: Just tested that! Thanks a looot!

Comment: Glad to hear that. You may mark it as the accepted answer, if so.